# Changing body css by clicking in menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parallax

I'm currently working on my new website and I need help.

When you open the site you get a landing page with icons (sort of menu bar) and you can't scroll.
When you click, tadaaaa it is a one page design. I am thinking about a `javascript`/`jquery` kind of script.

Current css:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Example `jquery`:

```
$("nav").on("click", function(e) {
    $('html, body').css('overflowY', 'visible');
}
```

I am quite a noob about this so don't blame me for a weird kind of script. I am trying to learn `javascript` and `jquery`.

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: And your question is? Go right on, you are on the right way. Alternative approach would be to work with different classes for body and simply change/add/remove the classname when clicking on the element.

Comment: i read the question twice..could not make out what exactly is your problem!

Comment: Question is.. how do i do this.. beacause when i use this one, it does not work.

Comment: @MikePluijlaar I think to solve this we'll need more code, this works as expected. Just to be sure, have you jQuery loaded before using it? Also you're having a `nav` element to click, I mean `nav` is not an `id` of some element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this by adding a class to your page to indicate its state, and then change the styling in your stylesheet.

HTML:
    
      
        Show whole page

Congratulations. You are viewing the page

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#loadpage").click(function () {
        $("html").addClass("loaded");
  });

});
```

CSS:

```
#page { display: none; }
html.loaded #page { display: block; }
html.loaded #loadpage { display: none; }
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/FHPzb/